# Selenium WebDriver IE performance

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id='3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']"));
```

=15.0s

---

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id$='NewSiteMaintenanceButton']"));
```

=18.4s

---

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton"));
```

> NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with css selector == #3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton

---

```
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton"));
```

=12.58s

---

Chrome and FireFox complete the entire test in *4 and 6 seconds* respectively, while IE takes *12-18 seconds* to find a single DOM element. Why is IE so much slower, and how can I increase performance?

Comment: What about using `_driver.FindElement(By.Id(...))`? For ID match I believe that one should be most efficient?

Comment: @shri046 "Unable to find element with id == #3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton"

Comment: You don't need `#` prefix if you are using ID match. `_driver.FindElement(By.Id("3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton"));`. That still poses a question about the validity of ID as @BoltClock mentioned.

Comment: @shri046 That works! But yeah, the id's are not valid

Comment: Good to know! Can you please update your post with the timing on the find by ID? Just for historical reference it would be a nice to have as a validation.

Comment: @shri046 Okay, I added it. It takes 12 seconds to find the element with ID,  why does it take so long??

Comment: 12 seconds is an awful long time to find an element. Can you post the relevant code snippet that shows how the timing stat is being generated?

Comment: @shri046 It's the only line in a Nunit test

Comment: So the timing you posted is the complete run time for the test? Point being if you don't have timer calls surrounding just the find element call, you might be looking at driver start/stop and other timing constraints. This is if you are looking purely at the test run time in comparison to Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

An ID selector cannot begin with a digit, because [a CSS identifier cannot begin with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). If you had not quoted the value in your attribute selectors, they would both fail for the same reason (although it is strange that it results in a NoSuchElementException instead of something else, because technically the selector is invalid).

To use an ID selector, you need to escape the initial digit. If the digit is coming from a variable, you can still escape it separately, just place the escape immediately after the hash:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#\\" + prefex + "_NewSiteMaintenanceButton"));
```

Comment: @James Madison: Updated my answer.